# Why is the address to argv different from the address of argv[0]?

Tags: c

I have been messing a bit with C lately and i have come across some "weird" behavior

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  printf("&argv=%d\n&argv[0]=%d\n", &argv, &(argv[0]));
  return 0;
}
```

the pointer to argv is completely different from the pointer of argv[0]
as C arrays are contiguous shouldn't the pointer to the argv be the same to the start of the first C string?
in my head the argv should look something like this

```c
char **argv = {char *, char *, char *};
```

where the start of the argv array be the same as the start of the first string
how is this structured and why aren't the two pointers the same?

Comment: `%d` is not the right format specifier for pointers. Use `%p` while casting the pointers to `(void*)`

Comment: Also, `argv` is not an array. It is a pointer. So after you take address of it `&argv` you get the address of a pointer. This is different from the case where `argv` is an array, Print `argv` instead of `&argv`.

Comment: @OP *i have been messing a bit with C lately* -- Don't tag this as C++ if you're coding in C.  As an example, the C++ way to output information is `std::cout`, which gives you type safety, unlike `printf`.  Removed C++ tag.

Answer (score 7):

`printf` requires that you use the format specifier that matches with the type of the argument that you pass. `%d` does not match with the type of the arguments that you pass (it requires `int` or similar), and therefore the behaviour of the program is undefined.

I recommend avoiding `printf` in general (Edit: question used to be tagged [c++]), but if you must use it, then you can use `%p` format specifier for `void*`. You must convert the pointer arguments to `void*`.

---

Once you've fixed the program, you'll find that the addresses are indeed different. The explanation is that `argv` is a pointer that doesn't point to itself. Hence its value is different from where it is stored. It points to another object stored elsewhere.

> ... the argv array ...

`argv` is not an array. Function parameters cannot be arrays. `argv` is a pointer.

You can create an analogous structure like this:

```
char args[] = "./a.out\0example\0argument";
char* ptrs[] = {
    args + 0,
    args + 8,
    args + 16,
    0,
};

int argc = 3;
char** argv = ptrs;

// argv == &ptrs[0]
// argv != &argv
```

Comment: thank you so much, this really helped me understand this

Answer (score 2):

C arrays are contiguous, but on the one hand you took the address of the array, and on the other hand you took the addresses in the array.

This is perhaps more obvious if you print out the `argv[i]` values for all values of `i` like this:

```
$ cat pointer.c 

#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < argc; ++i) {
        printf("&argv=%p\targv=%p\t&argv[%d]=%p\n", &argv, argv, i, &(argv[i]));
    }
  return 0;
}
$ gcc pointer.c 
$ ./a.out 1 2 3
&argv=0x7ff7b3716690    argv=0x7ff7b37167e0 &argv[0]=0x7ff7b37167e0
&argv=0x7ff7b3716690    argv=0x7ff7b37167e0 &argv[1]=0x7ff7b37167e8
&argv=0x7ff7b3716690    argv=0x7ff7b37167e0 &argv[2]=0x7ff7b37167f0
&argv=0x7ff7b3716690    argv=0x7ff7b37167e0 &argv[3]=0x7ff7b37167f8
```

While `%p` is a better format specifier, your `%d` would have worked too, if you were printing out the address of the first element of the array (which is just `argv`) instead of a pointer to the address of the first element of the array (which is `&argv` and not what you meant).

Comment: Alex Nicolaou, "your %d would have worked too, if you were printing out the address of the first element of the array (which is just argv)" --> No. pointer arguments need not get passed the same way as integer ones.  Using `"%d"` with a pointer augment is _undefined behavior_ - even when the pointer and integer are the same size.

Comment: It may be "undefined" but as almost every architecture on the planet has the same word sizes and pointer sizes, it's very rare to find a platform where `sizeof(int) != sizeof(char*)`.  Feel free to name one to prove yourself right, and I can name 100 that show that for all practical matters the issue the poster was having does not have to do with `%d` vs `%p` but with `&argv` vs `argv`.

`$ ./a.out
&argv=-1338308976 argv=-1338308640 &argv[0]=-1338308640
`

Comment: "If a conversion specification is invalid, the behavior is undefined" C17dr § 7.21.6.1 9 is sufficient.    I've seen `sizeof(int) != sizeof(char*)` from MS-DOS large model to 64-bit processors and address space with 32-bit `int` along with some novel embedded architectures.

Comment: @AlexNicolaou You really don't need to go too far to find an arch with `sizeof(int) != sizeof(char*)`. x86_64 is one, and it is one of the most common nowdays. https://godbolt.org/z/6fvPxP9rq

Comment: @EugeneSh. is right of course, I guess that's a sure sign I've gotten too old. The two machines I have easiest access to both have sizeof `4` and `8` respectively for `int` and `char*` and one is intel and one is ARM. Then endianness decides what the output is which is really not helpful. 

@chux

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I am not saying you're incorrect and I see that I am quite incorrect but I still think it distracts from the main point of confusion here which is that the OP was treating two things that cannot be the same as though they should be.

Comment: AlexNicolaou. Agree that it is a side issue that need not to have been brought up first in this answer with "While %p is a better format specifier, your %d would have worked too,".

Answer (score 1):

> as C arrays are contiguous shouldn't the pointer to the argv be the same to the start of the first C string?

The address of an array is indeed the same as the address of its 1st element, yes.  But `argv` is not an array, it is a *pointer* to an array.  `&argv` is the address of the pointer itself, not the address of the array that it is pointing at. Evaluating `argv` by itself will return the address of the array. And as such, `&(argv[0])` is the address of the 1st element of the array.

Try this instead, and you will see that `argv` and `&argv` are two different addresses:

```
printf("&argv=%p\nargv=%p\n&argv[0]=%p\n", &argv, argv, &(argv[0]));
```

Answer (score 1):

For starters you shall use the conversion specifier `%p` to output pointers using the function `printf`.

Function parameters are local variables of the function.

You can imagine the function main the following way

```
int main( /*int argc, char** argv */) {
   int argc = some_argument expression;
   char **argv = some_argument_expression;
    //...
```

Thus the expression `&argv` gives the address of the local variable `argv`

The expression `argv[0]` is the first element of the array pointed to by the local variable `argv` that has the type `char **`. And the expression `&argv[0]` gives the address of the first element of the pointed array.

So `&argv` is the address of the local variable `argv` that is defined in main as its parameter. While `&argv[0]` is the address of the first element of an array that is defined outside the function main.

To make it more clear consider a very simple program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main* void )
{
    int a[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    int *p = a;

    printf( "&p = %p, &p[0] = %p\n", ( void * )&p, ( void * )&p[0] );
}
```

As you see the expression `&`p yields the address of the variable `p` that occupies its own extent of memory while the expression `&p[0]` yields the address of the first element of the array `a` that occupies a separate extent of memory.